# Tkinter max recursion depth reached after moving rectangle continuously

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to get a rectangle to move continuously like a while loop however whenever I run the program it says I've reached the max recursion depth instantly, any way to fix this?

code:

```
from tkinter import *

def move(rect):
    canvas.move(rect, 10, 0)
    root.after(10, move(rect))
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("400x400")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill = "red")
canvas.pack()
root.after(10, move(rect))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

As @stovfl said, you shouldn't use the [`.after()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/after-method-in-python-tkinter) method **inside** the function.

Instead, this would be your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
def move(rectangle):
    canvas.move(rect, 10, 0)
    root.after(10, lambda: move(rect))

rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill = "red")
root.after(10, lambda: move(rect))
root.mainloop()
```

Or, if you want to do it differently for some reason,

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
def move(rectangle):
    canvas.move(rect, 10, 0)
    root.after(10, lambda: move(rect))

rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill = "red")
move(rect)
root.mainloop()
```

Both of them work perfectly, though the former is more consistent(at least in my opinion).

Hope this helps!